# Double-clicking a button doesn't open its code-behind

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm making a windows form using c# and added 3 buttons. When I double click on any object, it takes me to the code, the specific function that gets called when that object is activated, depending on its type. However, when I double click on the 2nd or 3rd buttons, it takes me to button 1's code instead of opening the function called by double clicking on the button I pressed.

Help?

Comment: Sharing your code-behind and relevant code from a generated form code would be really helpful.

Comment: Maybe button1's function *is* called? Which function is called is not decided by the function name. It may well be that all your buttons call the same function, `button1_Click`.

Comment: if I have 3 buttons, button1, button2, and button3, why would they all call button1_click, then I can't assign different functions to them.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            decimal phystrait = 0;
            decimal physskill = 0;
            decimal physpower = 0;
            decimal soctrait = 0;
            decimal socskill = 0;
            ...

Comment: Instead of double-click you can edit event handlers in the Properties window for every button.

Comment: can I ask the origin of the term "code-behind"? last time I programmed was in college before an ANSII/ISO standard for C++. so this is my first time using a VDE better than mid-90's boreland or codewarrior

Comment: I apologize I haven't really learned the VS2013 interface yet. So I might trip up on some newb stuff like that. It's going pretty well so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens when all 3 buttons are assigned to the same event. Select the 2 wrong buttons and delete their event in the properties window. Now doubleclicking **one** of them will create a new code template for it.. You probably had the three all selected when you created the 1st event..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the button click events via the properties window for each button and re-assign them apart.